# Error Importing dbf File Into GRASS

Tags: grass-gis, import, dbf

I am working on an assignment which requires me to connect to a database, then import a dbf file into the database using the command `db.in.ogr` (as can be seen below). However, GRASS simply won't import the dbf file. Is there something wrong with the file perhaps? I know for a fact that the file is there, so the problem must be another.

> (Sun May 27 09:40:58 2012)
>   db.in.ogr --verbose dsn=C:\datasource\clc2000\CLC2000LEGEND.DBF
>   output=landcover_legend GRASS_INFO_ERROR(4804,1): Unable to open data
>   source  ERROR: Input table
>    not found or not readable (Sun
>   May 27 09:41:00 2012) Command finished (1 sec)

Comment: can you open the dbf-file with another tool (libre-office..)?

Comment: Further to what Kurt says, can you try importing a different file, to see if that works? If so, perhaps your .dbf is corrupt?

Comment: Hi Kurt, yes I can. In fact I tried saving it also as xml and csv, but grass still wont import them.

Comment: Is the file online available for a test?

Comment: did you try it using Grass GUI?

Answer (score 1):

Try reducing the file name to less than 10 characters and start with a letter, e.g. cl2000.dbf

Answer (score 0):

I guess that you are on a case sensitive system. Try importing as "clc2000legend.dbf" (not "CLC2000LEGEND.DBF").

Comment: Hi, that didn't work either. Still the same error...